# Element commuting with normal subgroup of $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime. Suppose $N\triangleleft G$ where $|G| = p^n$ ($n>2$) and $|N| = p$. Prove there exists $g\not\in N$ such that $gn = ng$ for all $n\in N$.

I am supposed to prove this without using the class equation, as we have not gotten there in our group theory course yet. So I cannot just use that $p$-groups have nontrivial center. How could I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_{G}(N)$ denote the set of elements in $G$ commuting with all elements of $N$. Observe that $C_{G}(N)$ in fact forms a subgroup, and $N \le C_{G}(N)$, so $|C_{G}(N)| \ge p$.

Assume $|C_{G}(N)| = p$. As $N$ is normal in $G$, the conjugation action of $G$ preserves $N$. That is, for every $g \in G$, we have a permutation of $|N|$ elements given by $\phi_{g} (n) = g^{-1} n g$. Then $g\mapsto \phi_g$ is a homomorphism from $G \to S_{|N|}$.

Note that $C_{G}(N)$ is exactly the kernel of this homomorphism. Therefore, by the first isomorphism theorem, $G/C_{G}(N) \le S_{|N|}$. Looking at orders, we have $|G/C_{G}(N)| = p^{n-1}$ must divide $|N| = p$. As $n>2$, this is impossible.

Thus, $|C_{G}(N)| > p$, meaning there is an element of $C_{G}(N)$ that is not in $N$.